# Change height of div with jquery after ajax returns data

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I have a div which is always the same height as the div next to it (depending how much content is loaded in that div etc).

This works fine, but now I added a search function using jquery, it stopped working. When I search, the element that is used in the jquery calculation is loaded again. So I tried adding the jquery code inside the ajax callback, but this didn't work either. What should I do?

My code:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  var contenthoogte = $(".news-content").height();
  $(".contenthoogteaangepast").css("height", contenthoogte);
}).resize();
```

My HTML:

```
  <div class="col-sm-4 padding-zero contenthoogteaangepast">
        <form action="ajax/result.php" id="zoeken">
            <div class="zoekveld">
                <input class="inputzoek" type="text" placeholder="zoeken..." name="zoekwaarde">
                <input class="inputbutton" type="submit" value="Zoeken">
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="downloads">
            <h4>Downloads</h4>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">- PDF Voorbeeld 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">- PDF Voorbeeld 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">- PDF Voorbeeld 3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 padding-zero" id="result">
        <div class="box large-width-box-w1 full-width-box news-right entry-content news-content">
                <?
                if($zoekwaarde != ''){
                    $zoekresultcon = $conn->query($zoekresult);
                    while($zoekresult = $zoekresultcon->fetch_assoc()){
                        $zoekresultaten .= '<div class="zoekresultaat"><h4>'.$zoekresult['title'].'</h4></div>';
                    }
                    echo $zoekresultaten;
                }else{
                    ?>
                    <h2 class="port-tit contenttitle"><? echo $content['title']; ?></h2>
                    <?

                    //Replace img met img src="cms/ zodat je ook tussen de tekst images kan toevoegen
                    $replaced = str_replace('img src="','img src="cms/',$content['introtext']);
                    echo $replaced;
                }
                ?>

        </div>
    </div>
```

This is what I tried with ajax:

```
$( "#zoeken" ).submit(function( event ) {
  // Stop form from submitting normally
  event.preventDefault();
  // Get some values from elements on the page:
  var $form = $( this ),
    zoekvalue = $form.find( 'input[name="zoekwaarde"]' ).val(),
    url = $form.attr( "action" );
  // Send the data using post
  var posting = $.post( url, { zoekwaarde: zoekvalue } );
  // Put the results in a div
  posting.done(function( data ) {
    $(window).resize(function() {
      var contenthoogte = $(".news-content").height();
      $(".contenthoogteaangepast").css("height", contenthoogte);
    }).resize();
    $("#result").html(data);

  });
});
```

It should be changed even without resizing the screen so I also tried copying the code outside the .resize function, but this also didn't change anything.

Comment: You are triggering resize event before setting the `#result` content. Anyway, you shouldn't nest events

Answer (score 0):

First things first. You really shouldn't mix languages when programming. Even for a native Dutchie like me, this is very confusing to read. I've replaced all Dutch words for English equivalents.

Like A. Wolff said it's bad to mix events. So let's restructure some things.

First I've removed the window resize and replaced it with a call to `resizeContainer`. This function handles the resizing of your container. This function is also called in the window resize event.

```
function resizeContainer() {
  var contentheight = $(".news-content").height();
  $(".contentheightaltered").css("height", contentheight);
}

$(window).resize(function() {
  resizeContainer()
}).resize();

$( "#search" ).submit(function( event ) {
  // Stop form from submitting normally
  event.preventDefault();
  // Get some values from elements on the page:
  var $form = $( this ),
    searchvalue = $form.find( 'input[name="searchval"]' ).val(),
    url = $form.attr( "action" );
  // Send the data using post
  var posting = $.post( url, { searchval: searchvalue } );
  // Put the results in a div
  posting.done(function( data ) {
    $("#result").html(data);
    // Resize the compagnion container AFTER the data has been updated
    resizeContainer();
  });
});
```

This approach means that you don't repeat code, instead bundle it in a function that is called multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked with me :

```
$( "#contenthoogteaangepast" ).on( "changeHeight", function() {
    $( this ).height($("#.news-content").height());
});

//inside the callback of the request : 
$( "#contenthoogteaangepast" ).trigger( "changeHeight" );
```

or try :

```
function func() {
    $( this ).height($("#.news-content").height());
}

//inside the callback of the request : 
func();
```

I didn't try the second one but it should work.